# Using OpenStreetMaps (*.pbf) data with Mapnik?

Tags: openstreetmap, mapnik, xml

I am using mapnik to directly render a map using xml sheet.

I downloaded world boundaries, created the mapnik stylesheet from wiki page, and ran the python code which created a world image :

[image]

Now I want to create one of my college.

Would .osm.pbf format work to include its data?

Comment: The software that drives the Stack Exchange network flagged this Q&A as having the appearance of a "discussion in comments" and so I moved it to its own chat room.  However, I am not sure whether you will be able to participate in that chat room because you currently have [less than 20 reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat).  If that is the case please ping me (by typing @PolyGeo into a comment here) and perhaps AndreJ, I and another user can upvote your question to get you adequate reputation to get into chat.

Comment: I've upvoted your question to try to get you enough reputation to participate in chat. However, it would be far preferable for you to adhere to our focussed Q&A format when you write and **edit** your questions.

Answer (score 2):

The world picture is rendered from a shapefile. For detailed maps, you need to put the openstreetmap data into a postgis database using osm2pgsql (not osmosis!).

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mapnik can lead you to further instructions how to set up the database properly.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26058/discussion-on-answer-by-andrej-using-openstreetmaps-pbf-data-with-mapnik).